# Why is my apolloFetch call returning an empty query when called from within a promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, apollo

I'm trying to use `apolloFetch` inside a `Promise.all` in my Node.js microservice but keep getting an error that the query is empty. The reason for using `apolloFetch` is to call another micro service and pass it an array of queries. Can someone give me some direction? My code is as follows:

```
   const uri = "dsc.xxx.yyyy.com/abc/def/graphql";
   const apolloFetch = CreateApolloFetch({uri});
  const QryAllBooks = {
    type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
    args: {},
    resolve() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let sql = singleLineString`
                  select distinct t.bookid,t.bookname,t.country
                  from books_tbl t
                  where t.ship_status = 'Not Shipped'
              `;
            pool.query(sql, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(results);
                const str = JSON.stringify(results);
                const json = JSON.parse(str);
                const promises = [];
                for (let p = 0; p < results.length; p++) {
                    const book_id = json[p].bookid;
                    const query = `mutation updateShipping
                              {updateShipping
                               (id: ${book_id}, input:{
                                  status: "Shipped"
                               })
                               { bookid
                                 bookname }}`;
                    promises.push(query);
                }
                //Below is the Promise.all function with the   
                //apolloFetch that calls another graphql endpoint
                //an array of queries
                Promise.all(promises.map(p => apolloFetch({p}))).then((result) => {
                    //this is the problem code^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                    resolve();
                    console.log("success!");
                }).catch((e) => {
                    FunctionLogError(29, "Error", e);
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
module.exports = {
    QryAllBooks,
    BookType
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like apolloFetch requires `query` - you are passing `p`

change

```js
Promise.all( promises.map(p=>apolloFetch({p})) )
```

to

```js
Promise.all( promises.map(query=>apolloFetch({query})) )
```

You also call resolve twice

To resolve all errors or success

```js
const final_results = []
Promise.all(promises.map(query => apolloFetch({
  query,
}))).then((result) => {
  final_results.push(result)
}).catch((e) => {
  final_results.push(e)
}).then(() => {
  resolve(final_results)
});
```

Comment: if you mean calling resolve inside the Promise.all block - I have that in there in order to pass my eslint tests which fails it's test if there is nothing inside that block. Could you suggest how to overcome that or maybe I'm doing the Promise.all itself wrong?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the `{p}` syntax works. That is ES6 "shorthand" for `{ p: p }` - what `apolloFetch` is expecting is an object with a `query` key. So you need to pass `{ query }` with a change in name or `{ query: p }` to pass the correct object that apolloFetch expects

Comment: I would also change the `promises` array to `queries` because that is an array of queries and in your `map` you are returning the `promise` which is returned from `apolloFetch`

Comment: No I got that part - I changed from p to query, and it is working now. Your answer solved my issue. Now I have to iron out some bugs like how to properly resolve that specific call and do the error logging so that I can log ALL the errors instead of just one error that might return (in other words, I have figure out a way to make sure that the entire array of queries runs, with those that failed being passed into a logger function).

Comment: Idk if that is what you are looking for but the edit shows how you can get all the responses and send them back

Comment: Will give it a try and see if it does what I need; if not, will create another question and post the link. thanks.

Comment: I posted another question specifically for error catching here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914590/how-to-correctly-trap-and-read-any-errors-generated-in-a-promise-all-call

Answer (score 1):

You immediately resolve or rejects once the `pool.query()` callback starts:

`if(err){ reject(err);}resolve(results);`

So unless the query fails, you never resolve with the results from the apolloFetch calls, since the promise is already resolved with the pool.query() results. I guess you're missing an `else` block:

```
if( err ) {
  reject();
}
else {
  const promises = ...
}
```

PS: you can try using node.js' util.promisify() to turn `pool.query()` into a promise as well so you can just write something resembling: `query(...).then(results=>results.map(apolloFetch)` instead of ahving to mix callbacks and promises.

Comment: pool.query is that standard that rest of my team is using and if I change that pattern, I'll get frowned upon. To you first part - the pool.query is for the 1st query that returns rows that populate an array called promises[]. The apolloFetch is actually calling another micro-service endpoint with a mutation query. With that said, am I still doing something wrong in the pool.query and it's if clause?